# can't  Access Google APP Engine SDK

Tags: django, google-app-engine, djangoappengine

It prompts me:

```
The Google App Engine SDK could not be found!
Make sure it's accessible via your PATH environment and called google_appengine
```

when I run

```
python manage.py runserver
```

But It worked for my first time i run it.
I put it on my PATH directory, but it still prompts for that message. 
My os is Ubuntu 10.04, python version 2.6. that files/directories on my django project directory.

```
app.yaml   django           google_appengine  main.py      settings.pyc
autoload   djangoappengine  __init__.py       manage.py    urls.py
dbindexer  djangotoolbox    __init__.pyc      settings.py  urls.pyc
```

I don't know how to debug my problem.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I ran into this after updating GoogleAppEngineLauncher, but I had not yet run the application.  I ran GoogleAppEngineLauncher and it unpacked files and created the necessary symlinks.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put your sdk to Environment Path

**export PATH=$PATH:/home/computer_name/Desktop/google_appengine/**

Hope it helps,

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem, just move the  google_appengine  to `/usr/local` direcitory, i used to move to `/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-package`, after checking `sys.path`, I found it not in it.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, Google changed the path of the app engine SDK folder and django-nonrel can no longer find it. You need to edit the file `djangoappengine\boot.py` so that it can now find it. On line `50` add the following lines underneath `if os.name in ('nt', 'dos')`:

```
   paths.append(r'%(PROGRAMFILES(X86))s\Google\Cloud SDK'
                r'\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\third_party\appengine' %
                os.environ)
```